# How to force IAR to keep linking interrupt related functions?

Tags: c, static, linker, embedded, iar

[Clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eohX.png)

I would like to build an embedded software from static C libraries. My main problem is that the software links, but it doesn't run since the interrupt related functions are missing from the map file of the end product. (at least, this is my assumption)

I have read the linker manuals from IAR, tried a lot of settings but none of it worked.

You can find a .map file comparison below, the left one is what it supposed to be, right one is the result I get from building from libraries.

[.map compare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1HTv.png)

My interrupt vector table:

[Vector table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsEoX.png)

If it matters, the target processor is an ARM.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"tried a lot of settings but none of it worked."* Please list things you tried, that should have helped but didn't.

Comment: If you don't reference something, the linker won't pull it in.   My expectation is you're not actually referencing your interrupt functions anywhere in your code.

Comment: @user694733 
- Switching between 2 static lib generation mode (Static library C and Static library C (IAR)
- Switching between automatic runtime library selection
- Adding functions to keep symbols list
- Lowering optimization level (I can't turn off since it wouldn't fit into the target)

Comment: Please show the Vector Table of your project. This is where you specify the interrupt handlers. Even if they are implemented by the libraries, you still have to map them at the right location in memory.

Comment: Note that you may have to include *keep* directive for the *vector table* (not only the functions) in your linker script(s) or linker settings to make sure that symbols are not removed when they are not referred by other code as RussSchultz mentions.

Comment: #pragma location = "InterruptHandlerVectorTable"
const vtable_element_t InterruptHandler_Peripheral_VectorTable_au32[INTERRUPTHANDLER_VECTORTABLE_SIZE] =
{
    &InterruptHandler_Api_onWakeupTimerVectorCall,      // Wakeup timer
    &InterruptHandler_DefualtISR,                       // External interrupt0
    &InterruptHandler_DefualtISR,                       // External interrupt1
    &InterruptHandler_DefualtISR,                       // Watchdog timer
    &InterruptHandler_DefualtISR,                       // GP timer
    &InterruptHandler_Api_onADCVectorCall,    etc.

};

Comment: Please do not put additional information in the comments. [Edit] your question instead, and make sure all of the relevant information is there correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with IAR specifically, but in general the linker will resolve vector-table symbols using "weak-link" stubs provided in the start-up code if no *stronger* link is provided.

Reading the [IAR documentation](http://supp.iar.com/filespublic/updinfo/004916/arm/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf), the issue is:

> *The linker will not include a module from a library solely to satisfy weak references*

[image]

So if all your "concrete" interrupt handlers are in a separate modules with no other referenced non-weak symbols, the module will not be linked.

You can (probably) do one of the following:

1. Delete the weak-link implementations from the start-up code
2. Implement overrides to the weak-link implementations that call *differently named* library code functions. (i.e. do not use the default interrupt vector symbols for the library function names, but implement functions *with* the default names that call the library functions.)
3. Implement the weak stubs with calls to your library code rather then the default implementations (normally an endless loop)
4. Create a symbol in the module or modules containing the handlers and reference it in the code to force the module to be linked.  For example you might have:

   ```
    const int library_isr_force_explicit_link = 0 ;
   ```

   in the library, then in your application:

   ```
   extern const int library_isr_force_explicit_link ;
   volatile int dummy = library_isr_force_explicit_link ;
   ```

   Then the module containing the ISR will be forced to link to resolve the `library_isr_force_explicit_link` reference, so then the library ISR will resolve the otherwise weak symbols.

The first option will fail to link if there is no implementation in the library for any deleted weak implementation, which may be a useful diagnostic rather then a problem, but it does mean every project will have custom start-up code which will only link with your library.

The second will add a level of function call overhead, so slightly increase interrupt latency and stack usage.

The third is a combination of 1 and 2 and shares the advantages/disadvantages of both.

The fourth option comes from my understanding of the documentation - I assume it will work.

Personally I'd go with option 2 just to avoid modifying the provided default start-up - it may be less work in the future - especially when applying vendor provided updates, and to avoid any linker specific issues if you port the code to a different tool-chain.

The section "*Keeping modules*" in the documentation suggests using the *iarchive* utility to extract the object module and explicitly link it, but that rather defeats the object (no pun) of placing the code in a library in the first instance, and will in any case result in a complicated custom build step if you want to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this old thread, but I have encountered the same issue.
In my case the root cause was objects order passed to IAR linker.
If the vector_table object file is passed as the last one then linker does not remove weak interrupts handlers.